# Ruby 1.9 on Mac - Rails still loading 1.8 libraries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I installed Ruby 1.9 into /usr/local/bin and kept Ruby 1.8.7 in /usr/bin. Renamed all my 1.8 ruby, rails, rdoc, etc. executables to ruby18, rails18, etc.

So, going `ruby --version` at the command line gives me:

```
ruby 1.9.1p129 (2009-05-12 revision 23412) [i386-darwin9.7.0]
```

If I start up an `irb` session and look at the `$:` variable, which shows all locations that are searched for any `require` or `load` calls, the list is Ruby 1.8 locations that are part of the OEM Ruby install!

```
test
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/powerpc-darwin9.0
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/universal-darwin9.0
/Library/Ruby/Site
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/powerpc-darwin9.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin9.0
.
```

I thought maybe the `irb` executable was still pointing to 1.8 so I made sure the shebang was correct and it is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

I guess there's nothing inherently wrong with *also* searching in those locations for includes, but it looks like those are the only locations - it would never search for even standard libraries in the lib/ruby19 directory. What gives?

### Update

If I have Ruby give me the contents of `$:` directly and skip `irb` it looks like the list is correct:

```
ruby -e 'puts $:'

/usr/local/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/test
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-2.3.2/lib
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeresource-2.3.2/lib
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.0.10/lib
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.8/lib
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.0/bin
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/bin
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.2/bin
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.2/lib
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/site_ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/site_ruby/1.9.1/i386-darwin9.7.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/site_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i386-darwin9.7.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/vendor_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/1.9.1
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/i386-darwin9.7.0
.
```

So, that sounds like the wrong version of `irb` is being invoked. But like I said, the shebang line appears to be talking to the correct Ruby executable.

If I invoke `irb` with `ruby` directly then I get the correct list of 1.9 includes:

```
ruby /usr/local/bin/irb
```

This is *really* weird...

Comment: what do you get when you type `gem env`? (Assuming you've installed rubygems against your 1.9 install)

Comment: RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.1 (2009-05-12 patchlevel 129) [i386-darwin9.7.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby19
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-9
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1
     - /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false

(And a list of sources but I ran out of room to paste!)

Comment: That Ruby Executable isn't correct -- it used to be ruby19 but I renamed it to just plain ruby...hmmm...

Comment: Just updated to gem version 1.3.4 and it set its shebang line back to /usr/local/bin/ruby19 (which is what it was when I first installed). What config tells gem to do this?

Maybe something similar is happening to irb?

Comment: Based on your update  - are you sure you're looking at the right 'irb'? if you do a `which irb`, is it the one at  /usr/bin/irb or /usr/local/bin/irb? Granted ruby 1.9 and ruby 1.8, irb are the same... perhaps the shebangs aren't the same?

Comment: It was definitely pointing to /usr/local/bin/irb but as you see in my answer below, as soon as I started a new terminal session everything was fine!

Answer (score 1):

Well, what I ended up doing was just logging off the terminal session and starting a new one. Now when I run `irb` I get the correct list of 1.9 locations.

The terminal sure thought it was running the correct one before, though:

```
which irb
/usr/local/bin/irb
```

*shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe a case of Bash PATH caching then. In the future, can use `hash -r` to clear.